Compositum of galois extension and finite extension
Suppose $K/F$ is galois extension and $L/F$ is a finite extension. I'm asked to prove $KL/L$ is galois.
I think I need to split the question into 2 parts: separable and normal. Suppose $L=F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$, then $KL=K(\alpha_1,..,\alpha_n)$. I can't proceed in either part.
There's a prior problem: suppose $K/F$ separable, $L/F$ an arbitrary extension, then $KL/L$ is separable. If this is true then part1 is solved. However, I can't solve this neither.

Two first guesses A) this has been  handled on the site already. B) $K/F$ is a splitting field of a separable polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$. What can you say about the splitting field of $f$ over $L$?

@Jyriki Lahtonen Apologize if this is duplicated, but I didn't found that. For B) if $K/F$ is finite, $KL$ will be the field adjoining roots of $f$ in $L$, thus $KL$ is splitting field of $f$ over $L$. Separability of $f$ is preserved, done (Why didn't I use finiteness of $L/F$ ??). The problem now is that I wasn't given that $K/L$ is finite.

This is a duplicate question.
